# Problem when appending to 2D list in python

Tags: python, list, append

First I have initialized mylist as follows :

```
buf = []
mylist = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    mylist.append(buf)
```

Now mylist is like this :

```
mylist:

[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Now when I want to append a value to the first index like so:

```
mylist[0].append(3)
```

And I print mylist again I get this:

```
[[3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

Where it should only add the number 3 to the first list inside mylist as so:

```
[[3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

What is wrong with my code? when I don't use the above for loop to create embedded lists and I do it manually, I don't have this problem. And I need to do by using for loop because I need a huge embedded list, I put 10 there just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: You are appending a reference to the *same* list over and over. Don't append `buf`  just append a new `[]` with `mylist.append([])`.

Comment: Replace this `mylist.append(buf) ` with `mylist.append([])` . Reason is very well explained by Mark

Comment: @MarkMeyer nice, thanks